# What causes this error in a C++ app calling a C# DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, c++-cli

I haven't programmed in C++ since before .Net --  for Windows I use C# and .Net now.

I have a C# .Net DLL that I call from other C# programs with no problems.   But I have a customer who wants to call it from C++ so I'm writing a practice app to see how it's done.   **N.B. this is C++/CLI** i.e., it's a managed, CLI-CIL-CLR app.

In my C# program I add my DLL as a reference then in my code I have a *using* statement and then instantiate it . . .

```
    using ScannerBeam;
    . . . 

    CScannerBeam SB = new CScannerBeam();
```

. . . works a treat, no problems.   But in C++ I also add the DLL as a reference and do a

```
    using namespace ScannerBeam;
    . . . 

    CScannerBeam SB = gcnew CScannerBeam();
```

...and I get an error . . .

*Error  1   error C3673: 'ScannerBeam::CScannerBeam' : class does not have a copy-constructor*

Why does it need a copy constructor when C# doesn't?   Does it need a deep copy or just a shallow one?   Any other gotchas I need to know calling a C# DLL from (managed/CLI/CLR) C++?

Comment: I think you need `CScannerBeam^`.

Comment: Welcome to C++ where objects have a content - in C++/cli you have to deal with managed pointers T^ (pointers T*, references T& and plain values T)

Comment: @DieterLücking: `T^` is a "tracking handle".  And don't forget a tracking reference `T%`.  And `interior_ptr<T>`.

Comment: Bingo.  I guess C++ has changed since the old days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref classes need refptrs, CScannerBeam^ denotes a ref_ptr in C++-CLI.

Comment: Not so much.  `CScannerBeam SB;` is valid (stack semantics), but you wouldn't use `gcnew` to initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

`gcnew` evaluates to a tracking handle, of type `CScannerBeam^`

Your code is not much different from:

```
std::string s = new std::string();
```

which is also an error, the right side is a pointer and the left side isn't.

Just like native C++, use either

```
CScannerBeam SB; // creates an object with stack semantics
                 // it will be disposed at end the of the scope
func(sb.member);
```

or

```
CScannerBeam^ pSB = gcnew ScannerBeam(); // get handle to object on managed heap
                                         // it has dynamic lifetime and will live as
                                         // long as the .NET garbage collector can reach it
func(pSB->member);
```